# GitHub API: How to check for an organization's name availability?

Tags: http, github, command-line, automation

I can send an HTTP request to the GitHub API to automate creating new or deleting repositories, delete repositories, etc.

For example, I can create a new repository like this:

```
curl --user "$user" "https://api.github.com/user/repos" -d  {\"name\":\"$repo\"}"
```

I have been unable to any find documentation on how to create a new GitHub account or check if a user/organization name is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the other solution does not work, just visit http://checkusernames.com/

Comment: Nice one! Really practical.

Answer (score 10):

There is no way to create new users using the API. If you wanted to do this automatically, you would have to jump through a lot of hoops, including automatically confirming email addresses and you would probably be violating the TOS. Why would you want to do that?

Checking for usernames is much easier. To do this with the regular GitHub API, use:

```
curl -w '%{response_code}' 'https://api.github.com/users/<username>'
```

If it's a 404, the username should be available, assuming it meets all the username requirements (length, characters, etc).

An even easier way is to use what GitHub uses on its registration form:

```
curl --write-out ' %{http_code}\n' --data "value=$USERNAME" https://github.com/signup_check/username
```

This prints a little message if the username is unavailable and returns a 403. It returns 200 if it's available.

Comment: Even more useful than what I originally wanted to do. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, it says "Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub." I guess Github doesn't like the idea to check user name availability.

Comment: I'd also be interested in getting this to work with GitHub's cookie requirement.

Comment: `'https://api.github.com/user/<username>'` has changed to `'https://api.github.com/users/<username>'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` to query github and read the response 404/200 to determine the public availability of organization/user name

```
curl -o NUL -s -w "%{http_code}\n" https://github.com/ababc
```

The result will be printed as follows:

[image]

- As this is an http request it works without any api
- It can be used with any other programming/scripting language to bruteforce random name to find something that you like