# Modify Github profile by API but got "message not found" error

Tags: api, shell, github, curl

I followed this page to practice GitHub API and try to edit my profile
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/users

```
curl -X PATCH -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -H "Authorization: token MyToken" https://api.github.com/user -d '{"name":"myname"}'
```

But got the error message:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#update-the-authenticated-user"
}
```

I am very new to GitHub API, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have replaced MyToken by an actual [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token), registered to your account, this should work.
It should [update the authenticate user](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/users#update-the-authenticated-user).
Check first its old name (before renaming it) [does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30219553/6309) with curl and its [write outs](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/verbose/writeout):

```
curl -w '%{response_code}' 'https://api.github.com/users/<username>'
```

... Unless you are part of an organization that enforces SAML SSO for authentication, : see "[Authenticating for SAML SSO](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#authenticating-for-saml-sso)".
But I suspect this is not your case.

---

The [OP ITnewbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6327124/itnewbie) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66377998/modify-github-profile-by-api-but-got-message-not-found-error/66386194?noredirect=1#comment117370859_66386194) it was a [scope issue](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps)

> Removed and regenerate the token which includes all permission, then it's work!

---

[iqbal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1263169/iqbal) was, in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66377998/modify-github-profile-by-api-but-got-message-not-found-error/66386194#comment128065762_66386194), following the "[Get your own user profile](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api#get-your-own-user-profile)" GitHub REST API tutorial.

> When I changed the url from
> `curl -i -u your_username:your_token api.github.com/<<your user name>>` to
> `curl -i -u your_username:your_token api.github.com/users/<<your user name>>`, it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes I have the actual token when I testing. I even removed the last word of the token intentionally to test the token and got "bad credentials" as I expected. Seems the token is correct but still got a 404 code. It's pretty weird...

Comment: @ITnewbie Did you check the scope for your token? (https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps): at least `repo`.

Comment: I removed and regenerate the token which includes all permission then it's work! I think you are right. Sorry for the dumb question:(

Comment: @ITnewbie Great, well done! Don't worry about the question, it will help others.

Comment: I was following [Get your own user profile](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api#get-your-own-user-profile) from Github tutorial.


When I changed the url from 

curl -i -u your_username:your_token https://api.github.com/<<your user name>>

to

curl -i -u your_username:your_token https://api.github.com/users/<<your user name>>

It worked.

Comment: @Iqbal Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.